# Setting aspect ratio/screen resolution for cytoscape in headless mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, cytoscape.js

I want to calculate positions for graph nodes using cytoscape.js on backend. In a browser, some layouts use viewport in order to fit everything just right, but in a headless mode there seems to be no way of setting target height/width manually and layouts are trying to fit everything in a square. Is there any way to make it work?

More complex explanation:

I send a request from browser containing elements (edges, nodes) and desired layout (fcose, grid, etc.) to the node application, that builds layout in parallel and return calculated positions.

```js
cy = cytoscape({
    elements: graphRequest.elements,
    layout: graphRequest.layout,
    //mockViewport: {height: '1000px', width: '1600px'}
});

const positions: { [id: string]: cytoscape.Position } = {};
cy.nodes().forEach((node) => {
    positions[node.data().id] = node.position();
});

return positions;
```

However, some layouts use information about viewport to fit it. I'd like to send viewport height and width to my node application and use that information to generate positions fitting browser's viewport, but I'm unable to, as I'm running headless mode on node.js app and layouts get information about viewport from cytoscape container (which is not present in headless mode).

Comment: Please share your code and elaborate a little more about your issue

Comment: I've provided some more information

Comment: The solution was to provide  `boundingBox` argument for layout